# What is best way to manage spring boot applications on unix systems

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, production-environment

We have multiple springboot applications running on unix. It is very easy to start them by using java -jar .jar in a bash script. Now we are expanding. having more and more applications on spring boot. I am worried how to manage these kind of applications across multiple unix systems making sure that they are running and responding properly.

Do i have any other options apart from writing bash scripts, checking status etc ?
What is best way to manage multiple springboot applications ?
I see fabric8. https://fabric8.io/guide/springboot.html

Are there any good opensource platforms to support and manage multiple spring boot applications deployed across multiple systems.

Comment: To truly *manage* the applications, they should implement instrumentation, so you can monitor the internals of the application. Spring supports that, but the application will need to enable and extend it. See [**Spring Boot Actuator**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready.html) in the **Spring Boot Reference Guide**.

Answer (score 2):

[Checkout this manual here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) Spring Boot allows you to configure and run your applications as executables and as services.

If you are building a microservice architecture  I would recommend to use Spring Cloud and there is a default monitor system [Spring Boot Admin UI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-monitoring-management.html) or even Eureka would give you enough information about microservice status

Comment: Thanks very much for reply. It was helpful. Is there anything with spring cloud  to detect failed process and restart it ?(In few cases webloigc node manager can detect failures and restarts JVM. Not hystrix ) also scale up or down spring boot instances dynamically. I have seen something with kubernetes PODS which can scale dynamically.